# Nodejs_Uploading videos to youtube

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube-api, node-modules, youtube-javascript-api

i am able to uploading videos to youtube but while uploading i have to go through google authentication to select your account and channel. So how do i handle this in backend so that the user must not see any popups and upload video directly

[image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant the way Oauth2 works is that a user must consent to your accessing their account. To do that you must popup a consent screen for them to accept

There is no other way around this.